# Not able to define access rights

Tags: openerp-8

In `OpenErp`, how to restrict Team leads/managers of other dept suppose Developer from approving leave requests of an employee(from other dept(testing)) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set access rule for that,

```
Go to Settings -> Security -> Record Rules
Model = hr.holidays, Mark CRUD = True

['|',('employee_id.department_id','=',False),('employee_id.department_id','=',user.department_id.id)]
```

And set `groups` for which you want to set this rule. It will allows Groups member to set leave request of an employee which are belongs to his department or does not belongs to any departments.

Comment: I have got two models, one is hr.employee and res.users and I tried this rule.. but when i am logging in, i got the following error                                         ValueError: "'res.users' object has no attribute 'department_id'" while evaluating
u"['|',('employee_id.department_id','=',False),('employee_id.department_id','=',user.department_id.id)]"

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, you should try this, `[('employee_id.department_id.manager_id','in',user.employee_ids)]`